# Exit async anonymous method lambda expression Xdocument.validate which does not have a return value

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, linq-to-xml

I'm creating a async anonymous lambda method to validate an xml. However it's used to determen if the data should be read. By the first error the validation should stop. However when I try to exit it using an throw new exeption, a new error is created from the async method.

the errors generated:

```
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__139_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

I'm searching for a clean exit from the code below:

```
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemaSet.Add("", xmlValidationParameters.XsdSchemaLocation);

foreach (XmlSchema item in schemaSet.Schemas())
schemaSet.Add(item);

schemaSet.Compile();
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlValidationParameters.FileToValidateLocation, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace | LoadOptions.SetLineInfo );


xdoc.Validate(schemaSet, async (o, e) =>
{
// warnings worden overgeslagen.
if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
{
Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
if (ShowAllErrors == false)
throw new Exception("error found"); // error is replaced with the lines above and when run in a consile app. the console app crashes. Cause is the async method. When I dont use the async method. Everything goes well
}
}
);

private bool errorEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
switch (e.Severity)
{
case XmlSeverityType.Error:
// do something
return true;
case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
default:
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: You've shown the stack trace of the exception, but not what the exception itself is... and we're missing a lot of the context here. You've provided snippets of code, but not details of what you expect to happen (in detail, not just "a clean exit") vs what actually happens. A [mcve] would make it much easier to help you. It would also really help if you would format your source code - it's very hard to read at the moment.

Comment: Hi, what I want is to stop the validation when the first error occurs. The stackdump is generated when the throw exception is used.

Comment: I suspect the problem is due to the validation delegate (`ValidationEventHandler`) not being a genuinely asynchronous one... it has a `void` return type, which means validation will actually think it's "done" at the first await that has to wait for an ongoing operation. Fundamentally it's not built for async code, as far as I can see.